# Expanding QGIS mask Plugin query

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, expression, masking

When I select a polygon and I apply the QGIS plug-in mask to it then a buffer is created around the polygon.

The plug-in does this with the following expression in my case:

```
in_mask(31370)
```

Can I expand this expression so I can use it in another layer where not only the features or objects within the mask are given but also those who overlap or intersect?

[image]